# Auth and user management in laravel rest api

Tags: laravel, rest, authentication, authorization

I'm writing a rest API for a mobile app. I don't know how to auth users and admins in my app.
I have a table named "**users**" and have a field called "**isAdmin**" that is **0** or **1**.
now when admin sends posts, users can see posts.how do you recommend **auth** for both of these?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read the documentation about authentication on laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

**What you have to setup is the following:**

- Middleware (what routes can the user use and what routes can the admin use)
- Edit your model with an **isAdmin()** function to determine if an user is user or admin

---

**Example of a AdminMiddleware file** *- create by command line: php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return view('your_view')->withErrors('You are not logged in');
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of an User Model isAdmin function** *- create by command line: php artisan make:model User*

```
public function isAdmin(){
    if($this->isAdmin == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Example of your route file**

```
// @TODO: Set routes for user and admin here...

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    // @TODO: Set admin routes here, only admin can use this routes.
});
```

**You also have to edit your Kernel.php a bit:**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ... add this line
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

Comment: thank you very much.how do you recommend ? one table with isAdmin or two tables ???

Comment: @Steve I would recommend using the User(s) table with an isAdmin column. If you later on decide you want to add multiple type of users make an column as enum and change the isAdmin function to suite this requirement. Else you will end up creating a new table for a new type of user, this is not recommended.