# Laravel multi auth 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement multi auth in laravel 5.4 and have done it in this way,
i have already implemented guards and providers for the guards in auth.php,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FleetLoginController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:company');
    }

    public function showLogInForm() {
        return view('fleet.fleetLogin');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'

        ]);
        if (Auth::guard('company')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard('company')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function logcheck() {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            dd('yes logged in');
        }
        else
        {
            dd('No user logged in');
        }
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        $this->logcheck();
    }

    protected function guard() {
        return Auth::guard('company');
    }
}
```

i have made the providers and guards, the problem is when i call the function logcheck()
it dumps "No user logged in". Can anyone help me? i need to get the id of the logged in user by

```
Auth::User()->id;
```

Comment: Not sure if you want to use the same method but this is a post I made about different user roles and middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501968/auth-and-user-management-in-laravel-rest-api/46503658#46503658 might be helpfull.

Comment: I am using two tables. The  other one is basically for a company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to use send name to guard
`Auth::guard('company')->check()` on `logcheck()`

Comment: Now how can i use this as a middleware?

Comment: Just make `company` default guard in `config/auth.php` or add it in `app/Http/Middlewares/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`.